# Is it appropriate to cite a source that contains Chinese?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, languages, citation

I am a Chinese user. I understand we should use English in SE, but is it appropriate to cite a source that contains Chinese (the main content still present in English)?

Comment: Can you add a link to a source that "contains Chinese" with "the main content still present in English"? There are plenty of websites that contain Chinese characters but still have articles in English (if you want to be picky, on almost every Wikipedia page there are two Chinese characters). An example of what you are talking about will help clarify your question.

Comment: I might have misunderstood Op's question. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Though without the details that Willie asked for, it's a bit hard to say, my inclination would be that it's fine—if the relevant part of the source is not in English, it may be appropriate to note that fact and perhaps provide a translation or summary of some sort.

Comment: If the article is a primary source for a result, and happens to be written in Chinese, it should be fine, but you should be prepared to translate any excerpts you'll be taking from it into English...

Comment: @doraemonpaul, I hope [this Q&A on Academia SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1913/546) would be helpful to you. Sorry about my misunderstanding in the first place.